# Mode (previously: Median) of string column Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I need median of pandas data frame column which is having string values. but I don't know I am getting this error.Instead it is expected to give me the most repeated value. Why median function is trying to convert expected value into float

```
df_train["Electrical"]
0       SBrkr
1       SBrkr
2       SBrkr
3       SBrkr
4       SBrkr
```

Error:

```
df_train["Electrical"].median()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/nanops.py in f(values, axis, skipna, **kwds)
    127                 else:
--> 128                     result = alt(values, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, **kwds)
    129             except Exception:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/nanops.py in nanmedian(values, axis, skipna)
    379     if not is_float_dtype(values):
--> 380         values = values.astype('f8')
    381         values[mask] = np.nan

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'SBrkr'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/nanops.py in f(values, axis, skipna, **kwds)
    130                 try:
--> 131                     result = alt(values, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, **kwds)
    132                 except ValueError as e:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/nanops.py in nanmedian(values, axis, skipna)
    379     if not is_float_dtype(values):
--> 380         values = values.astype('f8')
    381         values[mask] = np.nan

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'SBrkr'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-79051d8f64cf> in <module>()
----> 1 df_train["Electrical"].median()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in stat_func(self, axis, skipna, level, numeric_only, **kwargs)
   9611                                       skipna=skipna)
   9612         return self._reduce(f, name, axis=axis, skipna=skipna,
-> 9613                             numeric_only=numeric_only)
   9614 
   9615     return set_function_name(stat_func, name, cls)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in _reduce(self, op, name, axis, skipna, numeric_only, filter_type, **kwds)
   3219                                           'numeric_only.'.format(name))
   3220             with np.errstate(all='ignore'):
-> 3221                 return op(delegate, skipna=skipna, **kwds)
   3222 
   3223         return delegate._reduce(op=op, name=name, axis=axis, skipna=skipna,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/nanops.py in _f(*args, **kwargs)
     75             try:
     76                 with np.errstate(invalid='ignore'):
---> 77                     return f(*args, **kwargs)
     78             except ValueError as e:
     79                 # we want to transform an object array

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/nanops.py in f(values, axis, skipna, **kwds)
    137 
    138                     if is_object_dtype(values):
--> 139                         raise TypeError(e)
    140                     raise
    141 

TypeError: could not convert string to float: 'SBrkr'
```

I have tried google and have seen stack overflow Question but didn't find something useful for which I am able to solve my problem. So How can I am able to get median through pandas? thank you guys for taking my question under consideration

Comment: The median does no return the most common value, that is the [mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)). Try df_train["Electrical"].mode(). See the pandas documentation on [mode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html)

Comment: ohh yes! Sorry I forgot ! True. I will try Mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The median formula is {(n + 1) ÷ 2} where “n” is the number of items in the set.

But you are trying with string, which is not numeric

If you want most common values try this

```
df_train["Electrical"].value_counts().idxmax()
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to answer to bart cubrich, if main aim is to find the max occurance of data than do as below

import pandas as pd

df["name"].value_counts().max()

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to do this. You could do a groupby on the column you are interested in

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_train=pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10, 2)), columns=['x','y'])
df_train['Electrical']=['a','a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b']

#method 1: mode
print(df_train['Electrical'].mode())
#method 2: groupby
answer=df_train.groupby(['Electrical']).count()['x'].idxmax()

print(answer)

Out:
'a'
```